# sws_scale on raw yuv420p data

Tags: c++, image, colors, yuv

I am getting camera data from my raspberry pi in yuv420p format. I am trying to use `sws_scale` to convert them into RGBA format. So this is how I initialize my context:

```
_sws_context = sws_getContext(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                                      CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

I am now a bit confused on how to set the data and line size for `sws_scale`. From the camera I just get a plain array of bytes without further structure. I assume I have to subdivide that into the planes somehow. My first approach was not to separate it at all and essentially have something like this (based on the fact that :

```
const uint8_t *src_data[] = {data.data()};
const int src_strides[] = {(int) std::ceil((CAMERA_WIDTH * 6) / 8)};
```

This was based on:

> there are 12 bits for a 2x2 grid of pixels

So I assumed one line would use half of this. But that causes a segmentation fault. So I think I somehow have to split `src_data` and `src_strides` into the respective YUV planes, but I am not sure how to do this, especially since one pixel for YUV420 data uses less than one byte per plane...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is simpler than I thought! The planes are one after another which also makes the strides pretty obvious:

```cpp
        const auto y = data.data();
        const auto u = y + CAMERA_WIDTH * CAMERA_HEIGHT;
        const auto v = u + (CAMERA_WIDTH * CAMERA_HEIGHT) / 4;

        const auto stride_y = CAMERA_WIDTH;
        const auto stride_u = CAMERA_WIDTH / 2;
        const auto stride_v = CAMERA_WIDTH / 2;
```